# How to define upload directory when uploading files with php move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, html, file-upload, cpanel

I am trying to add a multiple file upload to my website.I am uploading directly to my subdomain.  I have got the following code:

```
 <?php
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip","jpeg", "bmp");
    $max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
    $path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
    $count = 0;

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip file if any error found
            }          
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                }
                else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
                    echo "file has probably been uploaded";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

When i try to upload a file i get the `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`  and `Unable to move....file has probably been uploaded` messages. There are many other questions like this with possible solutions but i am trying to ask how to define the path to upload, beacuse I think I am mistaking there. Any other tip how to get thhis work would be helpful.

Comment: May be this is because $path contains an incorrect path that is not physically exist.

Comment: I am a total noob in this.I don't actually know what path to use. I mean where could i choose from? @MayankPandey

Comment: It will be a directory in the project directory like "/uploads" or some thing like this

Comment: Well in the cpanel i only have the css and the php/html files in the folder. Maybe i have to create a folder there to save the files. @MayankPandey

Comment: Thank you I actually fixed my issue. :D The directory I was using by now "Uploads" was not in the same folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If your in windows give it permission to write file.

Locate the folder>right-click>properties. And in security give permission  to write and read.

General purpose set to everyone

You path will be

$path = "./uploads/";

Comment: I am using linux , but I am uploading directly to the server, not using XAMPP or something. So directory on my pc wont help me, or at least I think so  . :)@Reuben Gomes

Comment: Did you check the below part.   Your $path has to be defined like

Comment: $path = "./uploads/";

Comment: More generally there is a checklist to troubleshoot this frequent error message : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory